# Data Analysis' graph problem with plotly, pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, data-analysis

I'm a newbie with data analysis and I'm following a course.
But I have a problem with some graph.

I'm trying to make a graph with plotly's library. I'm using "Netflix TV and Show" Dataset and for view the numbers of releases for years.

First of all, I have created an array in which I put 'release_year' and 'count'

```
Release=netflix.groupby(['release_year','type']) \
               .size().reset_index(name='count')
```

Then I create a bar

```
fig=px.bar(Release, x='release_year', y='count',color='type', 
           labels={'x':'Anno di rilascio', 'y':'Numero di Rilasci'},
           title='Rilasci')
fig.show()
```

1. First question: Why don't I see labels in bar?
2. If I want to analyze only "2019" or compare 2018,2019 can i? I need to save in a new array 2019 releases?

Answer (score 0):

For 1), assuming that you mean you want to see the labels when you *hover over the bar*, you can pass a dictionary to the `hover_data` parameter of `px.bar`.

You will notice the way the key-value pairs are interpreted when you pass them to `hover_data`, the keys are the column names and the values are the columns of the DataFrame you want to be displayed. I don't believe there is a way to rename the columns, so the values should be `False` for the old column names.

```
fig=px.bar(Release, x='release_year', y='count',color='type', 
           hover_data={
           'release_year':False,
           'count':False,
           'Anno di rilascio':Release['release_year'], 
           'Numero di Rilasci':Release['count']
           },
           title='Rilasci')
```

[image]

For 2) yes you will need to create a new array, but using slicing it's not too difficult.

```
Release_slice = Release[Release['release_year'].isin([2018, 2019])]

fig=px.bar(Release_slice, x='release_year', y='count',color='type', 
           hover_data={
           'release_year':False,
           'count':False,
           'Anno di rilascio':Release_slice['release_year'], 
           'Numero di Rilasci':Release_slice['count']
           },
           title='Rilasci')

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Paolo, two things since you are new to SO as far as I can tell. If you found my answer helpful, [please consider accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) — this way other people with the same question as you will be directed to the right answer. 

And secondly, you have posted your followup question as an answer which isn't the right place for it to go. People won't be able to find it, so I've flagged it. You should post it as a new question so that other people can find it. I'd also be happy to help look at it too once you do!

Comment: ah sorry, my fault. i'M new and i was thinking to add my new question here for don't create another topic.

Comment: No worries! Hope this clears things up :)